# Все положительные, отрицательные и числа в скобках между скобками

Tags: регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

Как получить все числа в подобной записи: `string(1,-2,5*(4-2))`?

Пробовал так: `re.sub("([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)","found",s)`, но запись игнорирует скобки.

Так как же получить все положительные, отрицательные и числа в скобках между `string()`.

Comment: `[-]?\d+` так срабатывает, или надо их как-то еще по скобкам отличать?

Comment: @slippyk тут загвоздка, если есть ещё числа (вне  скобок), то они тоже находятся. Мне же нужны числа только в скобках.

Comment: `re.findall('[-]?\d+', re.findall('\(([^)]+\(?)*[^(]+\)', s)[0])`. Одним выражением не получилось